# how to get next four month with year in php?

Tags: php

i want to get the current month and next three months with year in a dropdown box, the proble is when November2012 comes then  the last month would be January2013, if the current month is december2012 then the nest three months would be

january2013
february2013
march2013

in the drop down it should look like

```
December2012
january2013
february2013
march2013
```

Comment: i could not tried for this i am not able to create logic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$this_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {
    echo date('M Y', strtotime($i.' month', $this_month)) . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: It will. You can test that giving a second parameter to strtotime with a timestamp: echo date("MY", strtotime("+1 month", strtotime("2012-12-01")));

Comment: This will not work properly on the 31 day of a month (or earlier if February is one of the future months). You need to base the time on an earlier date.

Comment: Put this at the top: `$this_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));`. Then any time you call strtotime, pass `$this_month` as the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo date('F Y') . "\n";
echo date('F Y', strtotime('+1 month', time())) . "\n";
echo date('F Y', strtotime('+2 month', time())) . "\n";
echo date('F Y', strtotime('+3 month', time())) . "\n";
```

Comment: That will not work on the last day of a month with 31 days, or earlier if February is one of the future months.

Comment: Try adding `$this_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));` then replace all calls to `time()` with `$this_month`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're feeling a little object oriented:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
$now = new DateTime(date('Y-m'));
$period = new DatePeriod($now, new DateInterval('P1M'), 3);

foreach ($period as $date)
{
    print $date->format('MY');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$t = time();
$m = date('n', $t);
$d = date('j', $t);
$y = date('Y', $t);
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    echo date('FY\n', mktime(0, 0, 0, ($m + $i - 1) % 12 + 1, $d, $y + ($m + $i > 12 ? 1 : 0)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$this_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));

for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {

echo date("M Y", strtotime($i." month", $this_month)) .'
';

}